# Django - execute method after sending output to user

Tags: python, django

I have a long (aprox. 1sec) diagnostic method to call for every user's request. This is perfectly fine to call this method after rendering and sending output to the user. How can I do that in Django? Any guidelines where I can find info about it? Unfortunately using any queue system cannot be considered.

Comment: "using any queue system cannot be considered" - why not?

Comment: @Daniel - now when I know more about request_finished it is possible. If I decided to do that before I would force me to update 30 action one by one - not very efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `request_finished` signal and start your function at the end of every request. Look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.core.signals.request_finished